# ADF group rows and store each group in separate file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to solve a data problem with Azure Data Factory (ADF), and I'm almost there, but I keep getting stuck.

We're trying to process EventHub capture files, group them on several fields, and store each grouping in a separate file.

So, let's say, this is the data in our Avro file (I'm skipping the default EventHub capture columns like EnqueuedTimeUtc and SequenceNumber):

```json
[
  {"Body": "{\"DataType\": \"Type1\", \"DataVersion\": 1, \"id\": 1}"},
  {"Body": "{\"DataType\": \"Type1\", \"DataVersion\": 1, \"id\": 2}"},
  {"Body": "{\"DataType\": \"Type1\", \"DataVersion\": 2, \"id\": 3}"}
]
```

I want to split this data into separate files, with a path based on the data type and version, and the date of the data, and 1 json object per line. So, like this:

```json
/Type1/1/2021-04-22.json
{"DataType": "Type1", "DataVersion": 1, "id": 1}
{"DataType": "Type1", "DataVersion": 1, "id": 2}
```

So far I have the following steps:

- A source that reads the Avro files
- A Parse JSON step that reads the DataType and DataVersion from the Body, and appends them as the additional columns ParsedBody.DataType and ParsedBody.DataVersion.
- A Group-By step, that groups by ParsedBody.DataType and ParsedBody.DataVersion, and aggregates using `collect(Body)`
- A Derived column step that adds a column with the filename (ParsedBody.DataType + "/" + ParsedBody.DataVersion + "/" + $year + "*" + $month + "*" + $day + ".json"
- A sink that stores to blob, with the filename-column as the filename.

This will store the groups per file, but not in the format I want. It stores it like this:

```json
{
  "DataType": "Type1",
  "DataVersion": 1,
  "Body": [
    "{\"DataType\": \"Type1\", \"DataVersion\": 1, \"id\": 1}",
    "{\"DataType\": \"Type1\", \"DataVersion\": 1, \"id\": 2}"
  ]
}
```

And, as I said, I want 1 json object (not string) per line.

Is this doable in Data Factory at all, or am I using the wrong tool? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

All these primitives including reading from avro are in ADF dataflow. Use Parse Tx for parsing json and flatten for flattening. Use Sink partitioning to write to multiple files.

Comment: Thanks! The described steps are already dataflow steps, and I already use things like reading from Avro and parsing json. And yes, I know the sink can write to multiple files. The problem is that I want to have 1 group (from the grouped-aggregate) per file, with 1 json per line.

Comment: I assume the number of rows are not that big. Use a keygenerate(surrogate key) and add an artificial key. Use the artificial key as the partitioning key